# Elaticsearch 5.2, Python 3 AttributeError: 'Elasticsearch' object has no attribute 'delete_by_query'

Tags: python, elasticsearch

iam using  this code to delete docs from my index:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch 
es= Elasticsearch()

index = 'test'
doc_type = 'trends' 

q = {
"query": {
    "match": {
        "Device": "12 Bel"
        # find the docs those schould be deleted
    }
 },    
}

result = es.delete_by_query(body=q, doc_type=doc_type, index=index)
print('Result is : ', result)
```

i get this Error:

```
AttributeError: 'Elasticsearch' object has no attribute 'delete_by_query'
```

has someone experience with this problem ? Any helps?
Thanks

Comment: What version of Python 3.X are you using? I've run it through on Python 3.5.2 using the same code and it finds the function.

Comment: @KeirDavis : Iam using Python 2.7.9
 python -V Python 2.7.9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've checked the code on [https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py/blob/master/elasticsearch/client/**init**.py](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py/blob/master/elasticsearch/client/__init__.py) and the `Elasticsearch` class contains the `delete_by_query` method. So this should not happened. A possible reason is you upgraded elasticsearch-py from a old version (<5.0) and the old python library files are not removed. Try to remove the elasticsearch-py module and reinstall again, this should be fixed.

Comment: Thanks. The Problem is fixed by your advice

Comment: I was confused at first because calling the "info" REST endpoint showed a new version. But my elasticsearch-py *library* was an old version, like you say.